# MySQL using Strict Mode with subindex in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, strict

Using MYSQL 5.5 in strict mode, I am getting:

```
Error Code: 1292
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'C'
```

Using SQL below:

```
INSERT INTO table.t2 SELECT Something FROM table.t3 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(Something,":",-1) NOT IN ("C","E")
```

Data in 'Something' column could be like this:

```
2131:2134
2132:2134:C
2133:2134:C
2134:2134:E
2135:2134:E
2136:2134
2137:2134
2138:2134
2139:2134
```

I know I could remove strict mode, but like to fix this. Its my first time 
using "cast" while trying to solve this.... -1, gives integer or string

Comment: You should include the columns in the `insert` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the `where` clause.  The expression `'C' or 'E'` is a boolean expression, which is treated as an integer.  Hence, the error about converting a value to a number.

Try using `not in` instead:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(Something, ':', -1) NOT IN ('C', 'E')
```

Comment: In that case, list the columns in the `insert`.  That was my first suspicion, but then I noticed the malformed `where` clause.

Comment: LIke what? The insert wasnt giving a problem...Or, is it in strict mode.

Comment: @Merlin: What type is/are the target column/columns? What type is/are the `Something` that you are selecting? Do the types match?

Comment: Types match, exactly... When I remove the where clause inserts perfectly. But, i need the where clause.